# How Do I Attach a SQL Server Express Database to a Visual Studio 2010 project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, sql-server-2008-express

How do I do this?

- Attach an SQL Server Express Database to a Visual Studio project so that...

  - my source control contains the most resent schema for the database including stored procedures (can'
    t use SQL Compact Ed. because need to be able write stored procedures against the database),
  - can be version controlled using TFS without using tools like Red Gate Source Control,
  - can be automatically set up/updated when a developer gets the latest version of a project (using MS Build or similar build script api),
  - (would be nice) can be published after entire project passes unit tests.

Is any of this possible and if so how do I do it?

Comment: Out of interest, what's the objection to Red Gate tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want a migration framework, more than you want to store the actual database. Look into migration libraries for .Net like FluentMigrator.

Comment: Very interesting, I've never heard of this.  I think this could work for my situation.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I currently have used FluentMigrator on several projects and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like continuous Database Integration:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/Database_CI.aspx